# sftp and scp works fine when logged in, but not in a bash script

Tags: bash, scp

...and yes, I already have public/private key authentication set up and working. So I can e.g. scp without problems from the command line, but when I put the command in a bash script, nothing happens. The other commands in the batch file are executed, but not the ones involving file transfers. And there is no output. None at all. I'm at a loss.

And I don't have passphrase enabled.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the bash script or at least the relevant parts. And describe how you're actually launching this bash script that's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, sorry, found out. I had enabled rsa auth for my user, but as it was root running the script in cron, I had to generate a key pair for user root.